# any applications you don't need?

Tags: 16.04, uninstall, mate

Is there a list of any unneeded applications that I can remove? (I'm using Ubuntu Mate).

Comment: That list would be very dependent on your personal needs.

Comment: `sudo apt autoremove` cleans up old kernel versions and packages installed as dependencies that are no longer needed. But there is no mind-reading package management utility as far as I'm aware.

Comment: It's not at all like a package management utility, but Canonical's Project lead for Ubuntu MATE has published a list of key packages used in testing Ubuntu MATE 16.04 (see SahibPrime's answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Zanna has said in a comment, you can use `sudo apt autoremove`.
This automatically removes **orphaned packages**, or packages that aren't needed by the system.

```
myuser@mypc:~$ sudo apt autoremove
[insert apt output here]
myuser@mypc:~$
```

Any packages not removed by autoremove are required by your system.

***Do not attempt to remove packages you think are useless by yourself.***
 *You could brick your system by trying that.*

The [MATE Desktop GTK2 vs GTK3 memory consumption](https://ubuntu-mate.org/blog/mate-desktop-gtk2-vs-gtk3-memory-consumption/) webpage by Canonical's Project lead for Ubuntu MATE, Martin Wimpress, has a list of packages used when memory testing Ubuntu MATE 16.04. It might not be a good idea to remove any of these packages either.

Comment: +1 for `Do not attempt to remove packages you think are useless by yourself. You could brick your system.`.